# HTML Email created with ASP.NET MVC 2 View (standard view engine)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-4.0, viewengine

Is there a way to email an ASP.NET View using the standard view engine (not spark)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by standard view engine you  mean WebForms then you could take a look at [this blog post](http://www.joeyb.org/blog/2010/01/23/aspnet-mvc-2-render-template-to-string). If by standard view engine you mean Razor you may take a look at the [following blog post](http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/28/mvc-3-razor-view-engine-without-a-controller/). You may also take a look at [MvcContrib way of doing it](http://codevanced.net/post/Sending-HTML-emails-with-ASPNET-MVC2-and-MVCContrib.aspx). And also [DotLiquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/).

Answer (score 5):

Andrew Davey done a recent presentation on [Generating email with View Engines](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2-Andrew-Davey-Going-Postal-Generating-email-with-View-Engines) at [mvcConf 2](http://www.mvcconf.com/).

You can find out more information about the open source Postal project he created from the [Postal project site](http://aboutcode.net/postal/) or download it via NuGet.

It allows you to generate emails from the Razor view engine as well as the WebForms view engine.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to take a look at [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/) and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can render a view to a string then send that as the body of your message using:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage ();
AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString (htmlMessage, "text/html")
message.AlternateViews.Add (htmlView);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at MvcMailer? See the NuGet package [here](http://nuget.org/Packages/Search?packageType=Packages&searchCategory=All+Categories&searchTerm=mvcmailer) and the [project documentation](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide)

Hope it helps!